# Как работает функция внутри функции?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос по поводу декораторов в Python. Можете пожалуйста сказать что делает каждая строка в следующем коде:

```
def logged(hello):
    def new_hello(username):
        print('Arguments:', username)
        result = hello(username)
        print('Result:', result)
        return result

    return new_hello


def hello(username):
    return f"Привет, {username}"


hello = logged(hello)
hello('Вася')
```

Вывод:

```
Arguments: Вася
Result: Привет, Вася
```

Каким образом в logged передав Вася, получился Привет Вася?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logged` всего лишь возвращает ссылку на функцию `new_hello`, вы эту ссылку присваиваете переменной `hello` и когда вы потом пишете `hello('Вася')` вы таким образом вызываете `new_hello('Вася')`, вроде тут всё просто.

В `Python` в переменные можно записывать ссылки на абсолютно любые объекты, включая функции, что в данном случае и происходит.

До строки `hello = logged(hello)` переменная `hello` глобальной области видимости указывала на функцию `hello`, а после этой строки она стала указывать на функцию `new_hello`. При этом в самой функции `new_hello` осталась ссылка на старую функцию `hello` на момент когда отработал `def`.